# Can't view other computers on Network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, homegroup

***Systems:***

- My Machine: Windows 7 Ultimate connected through ethernet into router
- Her Machine--Other Machine: Windows 7
  Ultimate connected through wireless
- Router:F5D8236-4 N Wireless Router
  Version 1
- Firmware: 2.01.03 (Apr 28 2009)
- ISP: Comcast

***Problem:***

I can not view the "Other Machine" on the network at all. I opened command prompt and ran net view and saw the pc name. I tried pinging the pc and it times out. Went inside the router and tried viewing the computer on the DHCP list and it can not be seen. I restored the router back to default settings and firmware and completely reset the modem and router, and created home group. I went to the other machine to configure home group settings and made sure that both PC's had identical settings. She was able to see my machine but I could not see hers. I restarted both machines and now we cant see each other at all. Also her PC ("Other Machine") had exclamation mark in the wireless icon but was connected just fine. There is no firewalls on currently or anti-virus enabled, and still can not see each other.

Right now I am checking for updated drivers for the wireless card, but my question is could it be the router or something hardware related? I have went through all the settings in the Home group and visited most FAQ's and still no luck.

Also as it stands I can not view her machine inside the router DHCP Client List :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen cheap APs have problems with multicast/broadcast, especially with WPA or WPA2 security turned on. ARP, which is a critical low-level protocol for doing TCP/IP on wired or wireless Ethernet LANs, relies on broadcasts. Many protocols for browsing for other computers/service on the network are multicast protocols.

Turn off wireless security on the AP, re-connect her machine to the wireless network, and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I live in an apartment so having unsecured wireless isnt really an option I guess i need to figure out how to correctly hide the SSID and connect manually. I have heard it being done but never attempted. Is there a good guide that could help me step by step through this process, and if so do I also need to assign static IP?

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest you leave security off forever. I was suggesting you turn it off temporarily as a troubleshooting step. If that solves the problem, it means you've got a buggy AP or buggy clients. Contact your vendors for a fix or eBay what you've got and buy better gear.

By the way, hidden SSIDs are not security. It's like planting a tall hedge in front of your house and hoping robbers don't realize there's a house behind it.

Comment: Disabling the AP security worked great so I guess its time to buy a new router like suggested. Thanks for all the advice, and I agree with the above statement about hidden SSID's :)....Any good recommended routers worth buying which should run fine on mulitple broadcasts :)

Comment: It's hard to know at this point if the bug is in the AP or the wireless client card. I'd hate to see you switch routers and still have the problem because it's her card that's at fault. What is the make/model/version of the card?

Comment: the wireless card is internal on the HP Laptop/ Model: DV6700. its running the latest drivers from Windows 7 Update. It works fine on other routers